# Trouble serializing a class into XML using JAXB

Tags: xml, json, serialization, jaxb

I'm almost there but just cannot find a way to get the contents of my ArrayList to serialize correctly. Everything is working well apart from the List which produces entries in the XML file for each object in the list, but doesn't actually store any data that I could use to recreate the class file.

The current output is this (fightAreaCoords is the troublesome element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<userProfile>
    <settings>
        <targetSelection>1</targetSelection>
        <useFood>false</useFood>
        <exitOutFood>false</exitOutFood>
        <lootInCombat>false</lootInCombat>
        <useAbilities>true</useAbilities>
        <useSoulsplit>false</useSoulsplit>
        <waitForLoot>false</waitForLoot>
        <looting>false</looting>
        <buryBones>false</buryBones>
        <quickPray>false</quickPray>
        <exitOnPrayerOut>false</exitOnPrayerOut>
        <tagMode>false</tagMode>
        <tagSelection>0</tagSelection>
        <foodAmount>0</foodAmount>
        <fightRadius>20</fightRadius>
        <eatValue>0</eatValue>
        <prayValue>0</prayValue>
        <criticalHitpoints>1000</criticalHitpoints>
    </settings>
    <fightAreaCoords>
        <fightAreaCoords/>
        <fightAreaCoords/>
        <fightAreaCoords/>
        <fightAreaCoords/>
        <fightAreaCoords/>
        <fightAreaCoords/>
    </fightAreaCoords>
    <npcNames>Cow</npcNames>
    <profileName>test123</profileName>
</userProfile>
```

But I would like the  element to serialize like this:

```
<fightAreaCoords>
    <fightAreaCoords>Coordinate [3255, 3287, 0]</fightAreaCoords>
    <fightAreaCoords>Coordinate [3242, 3231, 0]</fightAreaCoords>  
</fightAreaCoords>
```

Here's the model I'm trying to serialize:

```
    @XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class UserProfile {

    public String profileName;
    public String[] npcNames;
    public String[] lootNames;
    public List<Coordinate> fightAreaCoords;
    public List<Coordinate> bankAreaCoords;

    public Area getBankArea() {
        return new Area.Polygonal(bankAreaCoords.toArray(new Coordinate[bankAreaCoords.size()]));
    }

    public Area getFightArea() {
        return new Area.Polygonal(fightAreaCoords.toArray(new Coordinate[fightAreaCoords.size()]));
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Settings settings;

    public void setProfileName(String name) {
        profileName = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getProfileName() {
        return profileName;
    }

    public void setNpcNames(String[] names) {
        npcNames = names;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String[] getNpcNames() {
        return npcNames;
    }

    public void setLootNames(String[] names) {
        lootNames = names;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement
    public List<String> getLootNames() {
        return Arrays.asList(lootNames);
    }

    public void setFightAreaCoords(List<Coordinate> coords) {
        fightAreaCoords = coords;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement
    public List<Coordinate> getFightAreaCoords() {
        return fightAreaCoords;
    }

    public void setBankAreaCoords(List<Coordinate> coords) {
        bankAreaCoords = coords;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement
    public List<Coordinate> getBankAreaCoords() {
        return bankAreaCoords;
    }


}
```

Which I create with:

```
try {
    File file = new File(Environment.getStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + profile.toString() + ".xml");
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserProfile.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(profile, file);
    // print out for easy debugging
    marshaller.marshal(profile, System.out);
    return true;
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@XmlTransient` prevents the data from being converted to/from XML.  That's the purpose of that annotation and you have it all over your model.

Comment: I thought they were necessary as when they're removed I get a "Class has two properties of the same name" error. I had this working with XStream earlier but I'm not allowed to add additional dependencies and just can't find a way of doing this. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @AidanO - Check out the following for "two properties" issue:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Thanks, following your advice I changed the access which has solved the error but the list still isn't serializing how I would like, I have edited the main post to show the issue with that element.

Comment: @AidanO - Ehat does the coordinate class look like.  If it's your class you will want to look at the `@XmlValue` annotation.  If it isn't then you may need to write an `XmlAdapter`.

Comment: Looks like I'll need to write an XmlAdapter, thanks for your help.